# Spring Boot not loading views from templates

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My Spring Boot project is not loading view from **src/main/resources/templates/login.html**. However it does load view from **src/main/resources/static/index.html**.

Here is my project structure:

[image]

I have added simple `<a>` tag for opening my login page in my **index.html**

```
    <div>
        <a class="btn" href="login">Login</a>
    </div>
```

**LoginController:**

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String showLogin() {
    System.out.println("Login method called");
    return "login";
}
```

This method doesn't get called. Moreover, I have seen many tutorials showing you don't need to add your view in **static** folder, just add your views in **templates** folder and Spring Boot will automatically pick it.

But it seems that Spring Boot is not picking views from **templates** folder and shows white label error page.

I am not using jsp pages instead I am on Thymelead template.

**application.properties**

```
server.servlet.context-path=/hisservices

server.port=8081

welcome.message: Welcome to the HIS Services Dashboard
```

**WelcomeController:** <- This shows **index.html** page

```
// inject via application.properties
@Value("${welcome.message:test}")
private String message = "Hello World";

@RequestMapping("/")
public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
    model.put("message", this.message);
    return "welcome";
}
```

Do I need to add explicit mapping for **templates** folder?

Comment: If the controller isn't called, that has nothing to do with views. Move your application class to the ... securejwt package.

Comment: move you `HisservicesJwtApplication.java` to outer/upper layer package i.e. `com.skm.hisservice.secueejwt`

Comment: please post code of `HisservicesJwtApplication.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you need to do package restructure.

Move main application file(HisserviceJwtApplication.java) into *com.skm.hisservice.securejwt* package and create new package *config* under *com.skm.hisservice.securejwt* and move *SecurityConfig*. No need to change another package.

By doing this, your *LoginController* will scan automatically by spring-boot and method *showLogin* would also called.

If, you want to continue with existing package structure(not advisable), then add *@ComponentScan('com.skm.hisservice.securejwt.controller')* into main application file.

Comment: Yes that's correct. It was all about package restructuring. Thanks. I created project from Spring Boot Initializer and it created this package structure. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Unless uses of **Thymeleaf**, Just Spring Boot could not find views from templates. You have to add following repository to your project to get solution. The way like this

```
main/webapp/WEB-INIF/*.html
```

Enter this two lines of code on file application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .html
```

**Now, run the project hope the issue resolved.**